# Pass slashes through nginx without treating them as directory separators

Tags: url, nginx, configuration-files

Under nginx, I have a page such as index.html present in a subdirectory or my web root, so that I can get to it via e.g. http:127.0.0.1/path/to/index.html

For obscure reasons, I sometimes want to append parameters on the end of this using a slash, such that they are ignored by nginx (they are read by javascript in the page itself). So I want

http:127.0.0.1/path/to/index.html/@foo?bar=x

to return the same index.html page, but without rewriting the URL, so that (for example) the javascript function window.location.pathname returns a string with `index.html/@foo?bar=x` on the end.

I'm not that familiar with nginx, so apologies if this is a trivial question, but how do I set up the conf files so that nginx doesn't look for a subdirectory of `index.html` called `@foo`? But so that it does still know that index.html lies within a directory called `to` which itself is within one called `path`?

Answer (score 1):

One technique would be to identify the part of the URI that ends with `.html/` and use that to internally rewrite it. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/.+?\.html)/ $1 last;
    return 404;
}
```

The URI seen by JavaScript should not be affected.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need to test whether the files existed, so I ended up simply rewriting: `location ~* /(\w+/)?my/special/dir/[^/]+/ { rewrite ^(.*my/special/dir/[^/]+)/ $1 last; return 404}` And as you said, the URI seen by JS was not changed